# Removing un-wanted commas in .csv file, after pressing 'submit button'

Tags: php, arrays, csv

here is the problem:

I have made a form field where people can enter their name and Adress etc..
When everything is filled and they Press send, i get the details in a .csv file.
However my problem is, when a field i empty or all empty, all i get in the .csv file are ' ,,,, ' .

Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">

    <input type="text" name="vorname"   placeholder="Vorname Eingeben">     <br>
    <input type="text" name="nachname"  placeholder="Nachname Eingeben">    <br>
    <input type="text" name="ort"       placeholder="Ort Eingeben">         <br>
    <input type="text" name="plz"       placeholder="PLZ Eingeben">         <br>
    <input type="text" name="strasse"   placeholder="Straße Eingeben">      <br>
                                                                            <br>
    <input type="submit" name='Absenden'>

</form>
```

PHP

```
$data = array (
    $_POST ['vorname'], $_POST ['nachname'], $_POST ['ort'], $_POST ['plz'], $_POST ['strasse']
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a+');
fputcsv($fp, $data);

fclose($fp);
```

Here is the .csv result's after the form is filled / not filled.

```
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5
,,,,
test3,test5,test6,test7,
test,,test,,
```

The; ,,,,
Those are the ones that im trying to get rid of, or rather more when the form is not filled so they do not appear.

Comment: put condition `if(array_filter($data))` before `fputcsv` statement

Comment: Check if `_POST` values are empty. If they are - not append to csv.

Comment: This is what i have tried : if( $data === !empty("")){
    echo (0);
} , i am new to PHP, so really i have no idea what i am doing, just trying things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the test before inserting any new line in your csv like this:

```
$data = array (
    $_POST ['vorname'], 
    $_POST ['nachname'], 
    $_POST ['ort'], 
    $_POST ['plz'], 
    $_POST ['strasse']
);

if(!empty(array_map('trim', array_filter($data)))) {
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a+');

    fputcsv($fp, $data);

    fclose($fp);    
}
```

Comment: Could you by any chance explain to me what  the if statement does exactly?

Comment: the `array_map('trim', array_filter($data))` will remove all null, false-y, zero-ish values from your array, so if the result is an empty array in this case you don't want to insert anything in the csv file, we could just use `array_filter($data)` for that but it may contains some spaces wich i consider empty result, this is why i'm runing a `array_map('trim'`

Comment: Thank you kind sir.